# I cannot get the new facebook like button code to work

Tags: html

I have copied and pasted the HTML 5 code for the facebook like button and cannot get it to work. Previously I used the I-Frame option and it was bulletproof and worked every time but now that option is not offered. I followed instructions and pasted the code where I wanted the like button and it simply does not work.

Code:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="pbcommunitytheatre.org/…; data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://pbcommunitytheatre.org/community-theatre-new-year-gala.html" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>

Comment: I edited your question, and put the code in there.  If that's all you have, my answer should get you there.

Comment: You're missing the closing quote on your data-href and have an ellipsis and semi-colon in its place. The syntax highlighting is a dead giveaway.

Comment: I missed that.  I answered when it was still in the comments.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Try using the Addthis or Sharethis plugin.. It comes with major social networking sites integration

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment and updated question, you're missing the script.  Add the following just below the opening `body` tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src ="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR-ID-HERE";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

If you haven't already done so, you'll have to create an app on [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com) so you have an app id to use.

As sevenseacat also mentioned, you are missing a quote in the provided code.  Corrected, it should look like:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://pbcommunitytheatre.org/"; data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

I also added the protocol to the link.